# regex find a line have wrong quotation marks

Tags: regex, quotation-marks

hi i need help to find a line have error quotation marks.

```
1 "many word " "many word"  "many word "
2 "many word "  " <-Error quotation
3 "many word " "many word " " many word  " " many word "    " <-Error quotation
4 """ but this quotation not match
5 "\"" this is not match
6 " aasd \" "  " <-Error quotation \"

only line 2 3 6 have an error quotation  

i need to find a line have an error quotation by regex
```

https://regex101.com/r/bWBV7A/9

Many thank

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/LF5P6l/1

Comment: hi can you help to fix line number 4 line 4 is correct.  it is a special case when it have 3 quotation mark. Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```php
^[^"\n]*(?:"""|"[^\\\n"]*(?:\\.[^\\\n"]*)*"[^"\n]*)*+"
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/3DpFRE/2)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^"\n]*                  any character except: '"', '\n' (newline)
                           (0 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    """                      '"""'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\\\n"]*                any character except: '\\', '\n'
                             (newline), '"' (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\\\n"]*                any character except: '\\', '\n'
                               (newline), '"' (0 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"\n]*                  any character except: '"', '\n'
                             (newline) (0 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*+                       end of grouping (possessive match, no backtracking)
```